# How to make q.all execute in order like async.series

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, async.js

Basically I am trying to figure out how to make `q.all` (or some other q function) execute in order the way `async.series` does.  I thought maybe `q.all([promise1,promise2,promise3...]).spread()` might work, but I'm looking for some sort of justification or another way to do it.

Comment: The section entitled "The Collection Kerfuffle" [here](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/) might help.